# How can I get the day of the specific date in java for android application development?

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: how to get the current day of the week (Monday, etc…) in user language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651221/android-how-to-get-the-current-day-of-the-week-monday-etc-in-user-languag)

I want to get the date of the specific day in java for android application development.
 eg. For Sunday
      7.8.2011
      14.8.2011
      21.8.2011

Comment: simple check this out [here](http://developer-dot-android.blogspot.com/2012/03/date-into-day-tut)

Answer (score 3):

```
  Date date1 = (new GregorianCalendar(2011 , Calendar.AUGUST, 28)).getTime(); 
   Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE"); 
    String s = formatter.format(date1);  //  s==Sunday
```

Comment: I think I want to get the result is opposite of this one. I mean four Sunday or five per one month and I want to get the date of each Sunday. Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `Calendar` Class. You can instantiate it using the `Calendar.getInstance()` method.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

i think its something like this  `cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`