# set day of the week when a date is selected from a date time picker android

Tags: android, datepicker, datetimepicker, android-datepicker

Does anyone know how to set the day of the week when a date is selected from a date time picker?

I currently have the following to set the date but I also require the day e.g *Mon, Tues*:

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            mYear = year;
            mMonth = monthOfYear;
            mDay = dayOfMonth;
            // calendar.set(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

        }
    };

private void setDateInEditText() {

    StringBuilder dateTime = new StringBuilder (mDay)
            .append("-").append(mMonth + 1).append("-").append(mYear)
            .append(" ").append(pad(mHour)).append(":")
            .append(pad(mMinute));

    datatableEditText.setText("");
    datatableEditText.setText(dateTime);

}
```

I don't want to set the current day I want to set the day of the date selected.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: how to get the current day of the week (Monday, etc...) in the user's language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651221/android-how-to-get-the-current-day-of-the-week-monday-etc-in-the-users-l)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout this answer on SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/7651306/1321873

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
Date d = new Date(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
String dayOfTheWeek = sdf.format(d);
```

Comment: hi. i've tried that one. it gives me todays day. rather than the date selected

Comment: Maybe you didn't notice how the date is created. Use the picked year, month and day to create the `Date` object. See my code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple code . you can modify the code as you like to get the correct output

```
  Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2012, Calendar.JUNE, 26);
  int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

The day-of-week is an integer value where 1 is Sunday, 2 is Monday, ..., and 7 is Saturday

Answer (score 0):

You can get the day of the week from the Calendar object. For instance:

```
Calendar mycal = Calendar.getInstance();
mycal.set(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
int dayOfWeek = mycal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
String dayString;
switch(dayOfWeek) {
case Calendar.SUNDAY:
    dayString = "Sunday";
    break;
...
}
datatableEditText.setText(dayString);
```