# Set weekdays programmatically

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am using [w2davids calendar](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/) and in that calendar, the author of the code has used an image (ImageView) to display the weekdays:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/calendarheader"
        android:src="@drawable/blue_bg_with_text"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ImageView> 
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

I would not like to use an image for the weekdays. How can I set it programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a horizontal `LinearLayout` with seven `TextView`s. You can set their contents using [`DateUtils.getDayOfWeekString()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getDayOfWeekString(int,%20int)). (I'm not sure if that `DateUtils` method is locale-compliant; if it's not, try [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651221/android-how-to-get-the-current-day-of-the-week-monday-etc-in-user-languag).)

In terms of formatting, using a center `gravity` on each `TextView` and a large upper padding on the `LinearLayout` should work fine, and you can set the background to whatever you need using a drawable.

Comment: Eric, DateUtils support localization! I've just get it display in Japanese correctly 日月火水木金土.