# datepicker selected day of the week android

Tags: android

I have date picker in my application and its works well .But I need selected day of week instead of date (i.e., if I select the date 23 I need to get day like "friday" instead of number). I used `OnDateSetListener` for click event.

```
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new         DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() 
{       
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
        int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) 
    {   

               }
       }
```

I need day in string(like monday(or) tuesday..) for `selectedDay` in above code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: how to get the current day of the week (Monday, etc...) in the user's language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651221/android-how-to-get-the-current-day-of-the-week-monday-etc-in-the-users-l)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

change your code as for getting day of week using `SimpleDateFormat` :

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener 
     datePickerListener = new  DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() 
{       
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
        int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) 
    {   
      SimpleDateFormat simpledateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
      Date date = new Date(selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay-1);
      String dayOfWeek = simpledateformat.format(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: @pros: i got the day of week in string format , but it gets previous day(such as saturday for friday,sunday for saturday). i use selectedDay-1 instead of selectedDay to get correct result.pls change it to mark as correct.

Answer (score 1):

This will give u the day names::

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
            Date d_name = new Date();
            String dayOfTheWeek = sdf.format(d_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use:

```
Date date = new Date(selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay-1);
```

It is deprecated and will give wrong output in some cases. Check with 28-jan-2015 and 04-jul-1940, both are Thursday but it returns Friday for 04-jul-1940.

Use:

```
GregorianCalendar GregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth-1);

int dayOfWeek=date.get(date.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

The above method will return an integer value:

- 1 - Monday
- 2 - Tuesday
- ...
- 7 - Sunday

Comment: But why would you want the day of the week as an integer?

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month,dayOfMonth-1);
int week_number=gregorianCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

You can use switch case to get week day in words.