# Displaying a "day-of-week" dialog in android

Tags: android

I'm making an app that requires the user to pick a time and day of week for a recurring event. I've already implemented a `TimePicker` dialog, but I can't seem to find one for picking the day of the week. I've tried`DatePicker`, but that's only for day of month. What can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966839/datepicker-selected-day-of-the-week-android

Comment: @ramedju for future reference when editing, please don't add "thanks" to the end of the post. One of the points of editing is to remove fluff, not add it.

Comment: Hi this question is already answered take a look over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270272/how-to-determine-day-of-week-by-passing-specific-date

Comment: @johnnyRose I'm sorry, but I've just added it to show some courtesy for those who have exerted efforts unto the question or problem. Thanks!

Comment: @ramedju it's nothing to worry about. Your edits have actually been very good. Just something I had noticed.

Comment: No, i need a dialog to pick the day of the week, not retrieve the day of the week from a DatePicker dialog

Comment: Could you just make a custom dialog with a spinner that has an Adapter pointing at a String array of Sunday-Saturday?

Comment: Alternatively, you could look at [this library](https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers) to see how the "recurrence" view is implemented.

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007.  I did end up just making a custom dialog with Sunday-Saturday

Answer (score 0):

I you want the `day of week` you will have use SimpleDateFormat and use `EEEE`
for example.

```
  public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
        int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) 
    {   
      SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
      Date date = new Date(selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay-1);
      String dayOfWeek = dateformat.format(date);
    }
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. They want a Dialog to pick the day of the week, not format a string

Comment: @cricket_007 you are right, I need a dialogue to pick the day of the week.

Comment: if you want a Dialog just create a custom Dialog which extends DialogFragment.and override the onDateSet  method like i did in the above. if this was helpfull don't forget to tick the answer. Thankyou