# How to start DatePickerDialog on the Current date?

Tags: android, datepicker

I have a method to return the current date by using the Calendar like this:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

On the other hand, I have a **DatePickerDialog** which I need to update the previous values.

```
private void launchDatePicker() {
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int nuevoDia = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int nuevoDiaSemana = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    int nuevoMes = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int nuevoAño = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int nuevoAño, int nuevoMes, int nuevoDia) {
            //int nuevoDiaSemana = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            dayOfMonth = nuevoDia;
            month = nuevoMes;
            year = nuevoAño;
            fechaActual(dayOfWeek, dayOfMonth,month);
            ajustarFormatoFecha();
            readFromDichos();
            faseLunar();


        }
    }
    ,nuevoDia,nuevoMes,nuevoAño);
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

The problem is that this **DatePicker** always starts in year = 1900. How can I start it in the current date?

How can I get **DayOfTheWeek** by using the **DatePickerDialog**?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing wrong argument to `DatePickerDialog` as

`nuevoDia,nuevoMes,nuevoAño`

It should be: `nuevoAño, nuevoMes, nuevoDia`

You can do something like :

```
private void launchDatePicker() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR); 
    int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int nuevoAño, int nuevoMes, int nuevoDia) {
            //int nuevoDiaSemana = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            dayOfMonth = nuevoDia;
            month = nuevoMes;
            year = nuevoAño;
            fechaActual(dayOfWeek, dayOfMonth,month);
            ajustarFormatoFecha();
            readFromDichos();
            faseLunar();


        }
    }
    , nuevoAño, nuevoMes, nuevoDia); // <----- correct arguments ------
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Waqar. I'll try. Btw, do you know how can I get DAYOFWEEK from the datePicker?

Comment: @Toni I hope you are looking something similar like this and I hope it works otherwise let me know :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/13966902/1868841

Comment: Thanks Waqar but even tho it seems to be deprecated, it returns an String of the day name in the language of my Android system wich its not usefull for me since I need the int between 1 and 7 so I can determinate in any language.

Answer (score 0):

FYI:

```
private void launchDatePicker() {
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int nuevoDia = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int nuevoMes = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int nuevoAño = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int nuevoAño, int nuevoMes, int nuevoDia) {
            //int nuevoDiaSemana = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            dayOfMonth = nuevoDia;
            month = nuevoMes;
            year = nuevoAño;
            Calendar c = calendar.getInstance();
            c.set(year,month,dayOfMonth);
            int nuevoDiaSemana = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            dayOfWeek = nuevoDiaSemana;
            fechaActual(dayOfWeek, dayOfMonth,month);
            ajustarFormatoFecha();
            readFromDichos();
            faseLunar();
        }
    }
    ,nuevoAño,nuevoMes,nuevoDia);
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```