# PopUp Alarm on selected days and selected time in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to popup an alarm on selected day i.e. Monday ,Tuesday and so on. And at selected time on every week. I've an idea about interval but I don't know how to get the next day and popup alarm ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and get a `WakeClock` while processing the `Intent` in `Service` (make sure to release it and chose the right kind).

Here is a great example :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8801990/220710

To get the day current day of the week, look at this question :
[Android: how to get the current day of the week (Monday, etc...) in the user's language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651221/android-how-to-get-the-current-day-of-the-week-monday-etc-in-user-languag)

Then you would use :

> *setInexactRepeating(int type, long triggerAtMillis, long intervalMillis, PendingIntent operation)*
>
> Schedule a repeating alarm
>   that has inexact trigger time requirements; for example, an alarm that
>   repeats every hour, but not necessarily at the top of every hour.

Then you would need to set :

- type = `RTC_WAKEUP`
- intervalMillis = ms in a week
- triggerAtMillis = `System.currentTimeMillis()` + ms to the next Monday, Tuesday or
  whatever
- intent = the intent you want to fire to a `Service` that
  will process it.

Comment: i know but i dont know how to check which is current day and pop up accordingly

Comment: Guys, also @Richa , I'm leaving.

Comment: @Richa Are you still having trouble?

Comment: @Richa Sorry, I don't understand the issue you are having.