# Get value of day month from Date object in Android?

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

By using this code :

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = format.parse(dtStart);
return date;
```

I have converted the String Date by Date Object and get the value:

> Sun Feb 17 07:00:00 GMT 2013

Now I want to extract day (Sunday/Monday) and month from here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: how to get the current day of the week (Monday, etc...) in the user's language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651221/android-how-to-get-the-current-day-of-the-week-monday-etc-in-the-users-l)

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 222, accepted):

```java
import android.text.format.DateFormat;

String dayOfTheWeek = (String) DateFormat.format("EEEE", date); // Thursday
String day          = (String) DateFormat.format("dd",   date); // 20
String monthString  = (String) DateFormat.format("MMM",  date); // Jun
String monthNumber  = (String) DateFormat.format("MM",   date); // 06
String year         = (String) DateFormat.format("yyyy", date); // 2013
```

Comment: This solution Worked....How can i now get the date value suppose "17" form this solution

Comment: ohhhhh this is your solution `String date = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd", date);`

Comment: Actually you only need to change the format of data which you want, rest all is same.

Comment: Can you show how to get the Month and Year ...Suppose "12" as month ..."1998" as year

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1183)at  android.text.format.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:348)

Comment: @ternes3 Check your code.. and if you have any problem post your question.

Comment: Hi Pankaj,
String year = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy", 01/01/1988);
i get year = 1969
Why year is change??
Please help me...

Comment: @135  Insteadof using `01/01/1988`, use `Date` object which set to this year.

Comment: Date date = new Date(01/01/1988);
String year = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy", date); 
Log.e("year","" + year);
It still 1969...

Comment: @135 `Date date = new Date(1988, 1, 1);`

Comment: What is the format you are using. without seeing your full code I can not help you

Comment: i also change format like Date date = new Date(1988, 1, 1);
and get 3888..
so have you any other idea @PankajKumar...

Comment: Right now i am passing fix like,
Date date = new Date(01/01/1988);
String year = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy",date); 
Log.e("year","" + year);

Comment: Very Nice Solution :)

Answer (score 28):

You can try:

```
String input_date="01/08/2012";
SimpleDateFormat format1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date dt1=format1.parse(input_date);
DateFormat format2=new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE"); 
String finalDay=format2.format(dt1);
```

Also try this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(yourDate);
int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Answer (score 4):

to custom days of week you can use this function

```
public static String getDayFromDateString(String stringDate,String dateTimeFormat)
{
    String[] daysArray = new String[] {"saturday","sunday","monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday"};
    String day = "";

    int dayOfWeek =0;
    //dateTimeFormat = yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateTimeFormat);
    Date date;
    try {
        date = formatter.parse(stringDate);
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(date);
        dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)-1;
        if (dayOfWeek < 0) {
            dayOfWeek += 7;
        }
        day = daysArray[dayOfWeek];
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return day;
}
```

dateTimeFormat for example dateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

If your date and time were meant for UTC:

```
LocalDateTime               // Represent a date and time-of-day lacking the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. Does *NOT* represent a moment.
.parse(                     // Convert from text to a date-time object.
    "2013-02-17 07:00:00" 
    .replace( " " , "T" )   // Comply with standard ISO 8601 format.
)                           // Returns a `LocalDateTime` object.
.atOffset(                  // Determining a moment by assign an offset-from-UTC. Do this only if you are certain the date and time-of-day were intended for this offset.
    ZoneOffset.UTC          // An offset of zero means UTC itself.
)                           // Returns a `OffsetDateTime` object. Represents a moment.
.getDayOfWeek()             // Extract the day-of-week enum object.
.getDisplayName(            // Localize, producing text. 
    TextStyle.FULL ,        // Specify how long or abbreviated.
    Locale.US               // Specify language and cultural norms to use in localization.
)                           // Returns a `String` object.
```

> Sunday

And…

```
…
.getMonth()
.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.US )
```

> February

## java.time

The modern solution uses the *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted the terrible old date-time classes such as `Date` & `SimpleDateFormat`.

## Time zone

Your code ignores the crucial issue of time zone. When you omit an specific zone or offset-from-UTC, the JVM’s current default time zone is implicitly applied. So your results may vary.

Instead, always specify a time zone or offset explicitly in your code.

## `LocalDateTime`

Your input format of YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS lacks an indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC.

So we must parse as a `LocalDateTime`.

Your input format is close to the standard ISO 8601 format used by default in the `LocalDateTime` class. Just replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T`.

```
String input = "2013-02-17 07:00:00".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

> ldt.toString(): 2013-02-17T07:00

The `LocalDateTime` you now have in hand does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. Purposely lacking a time zone or offset means it cannot, by definition, represent a moment. A `LocalDateTime` represents potential moments along a range of about 26-27 hours, the range of time zones around the globe.

## `ZonedDateTime`

If you know for certain a time zone intended for that date and time, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

With a `ZonedDateTime`, you now have a moment.

Get the day-of-week using the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum.

```
DayOfWeek dow = zdt.getDayOfWeek() ;
```

The [`DayOfWeek::getDisplayName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-) method translates the name of the day into any human language specified by a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) such as [`Locale.US`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#US) or [`Locale.CANADA_FRENCH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#CANADA_FRENCH).

```
String output = dow.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
```

> dimanche

Or, in US English.

```
String output = dow.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.US );
```

> Sunday

Similar for month, use [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum.

```
Month m = zdt.getMonth() ;

String output = m.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.US );
```

> February

## `OffsetDateTime`

If you know for certain that date and time-of-day in the `LocalDateTime` was meant to represent a moment in UTC, use `OffsetDateTime` class.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;  // Assign UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds).
```

## `MonthDay`

You may also be interested in the `MonthDay` class if you wish to work with a day and a month without a year.

```
MonthDay md = MonthDay.from( zdt ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

Also in Kotlin :

```
    val string = "2020-01-13T00:00:00"
    val format = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.US)
    val date = format.parse(string)

    val day = DateFormat.format("dd", date) as String
    val monthNumber = DateFormat.format("MM", date) as String
    val year = DateFormat.format("yyyy", date) as String
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the java.util.Calendar class.

```
String dateString = "20/12/2018";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

Date readDate = df.parse(dateString);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(readDate.getTime());

Log.d(TAG, "Year: "+cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
Log.d(TAG, "Month: "+cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
Log.d(TAG, "Day: "+cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin you can also get Current Day Name using this. (Requires API level 26)

```
(Calendar.getInstance() as GregorianCalendar).toZonedDateTime().dayOfWeek
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   DateFormat date= new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.getDefault());
    String dayName= date.format(calendar.getTime()); //Monday
    date = SimpleDateFormat("EE", Locale.getDefault());
    dayName = date2.format(calendar.time); //Sun
    date= new SimpleDateFormat("dd", Locale.getDefault());
    String dayNumber = date.format(calendar.getTime()); //20
    date= new SimpleDateFormat("MMM", Locale.getDefault());
    String monthName= date.format(calendar.getTime()); //Apr
    date= new SimpleDateFormat("MM", Locale.getDefault());
    String monthNumber= date.format(calendar.getTime()); //04
    date= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    String year= date.format(calendar.getTime()); //2020
```

that's it. enjoy

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String getDayFromStringDate(String stringDate, String dateFormat, boolean abbreviated) throws ParseException {

    String pattern;

    if (abbreviated) {

        pattern = "E"; // For short day eg: Mon,Tue
    } else {

        pattern = "EEEE"; // For compete day eg: Monday, Tuesday
    }

    return new SimpleDateFormat(pattern)
            .format(new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat).parse(stringDate));
}
```

Eg: if stringDate :- 16/12/2018 then dateFormat : - dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score -1):

```
selecteddate = "Tue Nov 26 15:49:25 GMT+05:30 2019";
```

SimpleDateFormat dateUI = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd-MMMM-yyyy");

String date = dateUI.foramt(selecteddate);

Log.e(context,"date");