# How to make a variable to this day in Android development?

Tags: android

I'm doing a Android App and I want to do a variable that will see what day of the month it's (like, if the user is seeing the app in April 18, I'll have a variable that will see that it's day 18), and then I could do somenthing like this:
if (today == 12){
...
}
else if (today == 13) 
(...)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192776/get-value-of-day-month-form-date-object-in-android

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = format.parse(dtStart);
String today = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd", date);
```

Comment: Okay, but is DTStart gives error, says it can not find the symbol, something. I'm newcomer it ...

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
int dayOfMonth= calendar.get(DAY_OF_MONTH);
```