# How to get the day like "Monday" string from "2015-02-24" in android

Tags: java, android, date

I have a string  "2015-02-24", how can I get "day name like Monday or Mon" in android. I try to use the code below but failed.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
                    Date d = new Date("2015-02-24");
String dayOfTheWeek = sdf.format(d);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: how to get the current day of the week (Monday, etc...) in the user's language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651221/android-how-to-get-the-current-day-of-the-week-monday-etc-in-the-users-l)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String input_date_string="2015-02-24";
        SimpleDateFormat dateformat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date;
        try {
            date = dateformat.parse(input_date_string);
            DateFormat dayFormate=new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE"); 
            String dayFromDate=dayFormate.format(date);
            Log.d("asd", "----------:: "+dayFromDate);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: What if I want to use this type of string "2015-02-24", How can I set it up ?Should I use "yyyy-MM-dd" ?

Comment: yes @user3867627. You should use that. It will work.

Comment: yes it will work also. i have changed my ans also. you can check it again. Its working code.

Answer (score 3):

Use Calender instance or use DateFormat

Simple :

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(yourDate);
int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Or:

```
String dayOfTheWeek = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("EEEE", date);//Thursday
String stringMonth = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMM", date); //Jun
String intMonth = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MM", date); //06
String year = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy", date); //2013
String day = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd", date); //20
```

UPDATE: you have to see Date in Java doc:

> Constructor Summary:
>
> **Date():**
> Allocates a Date object and initializes it so that it represents the time at which it was allocated, measured to the nearest millisecond.
>
> **Date(int year, int month, int date):**
> Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.set(year + 1900, month, date) or GregorianCalendar(year + 1900, month, date).
>
> **Date(int year, int month, int date, int hrs, int min):**
> Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.set(year + 1900, month, date, hrs, min) or GregorianCalendar(year + 1900, month, date, hrs, min).
>
> **Date(int year, int month, int date, int hrs, int min, int sec):**
> Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.set(year + 1900, month, date, hrs, min, sec) or GregorianCalendar(year + 1900, month, date, hrs, min, sec).
>
> **Date(long date):**
> Allocates a Date object and initializes it to represent the specified number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.
>
> **Date(String s):**
> Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by DateFormat.parse(String s).

Only Date() and Date(long Date) still usable.

Comment: May I ask you one thing? should I set yourDate with  Date d = new Date("2015-02-24"); ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to first convert the date in String format to a Date object. This can be done via:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = dateFormat.parse(date);
```

You can then format the above date via:

```
SimpleDateFormat weekDayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
String dayOfTheWeek = weekDayFormat.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are correct. I am just summing up the essence of all.

First you need to parse your `String` into `Date`, like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
try {
    Date date = dateFormat.parse("2015-02-24");
}
catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Your `date` is ready :)

But major functions of `Date` class are deprecated. So you should use `Calendar` instead. Like this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
switch(dayOfWeek)
{
    case Calendar.SUNDAY: 
        break;
    case Calendar.MONDAY:
        break;
    case Calendar.TUESDAY:
        break;
    case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
        break;
    case Calendar.THURSDAY:
        break;
    case Calendar.FRIDAY:
        break;
    case Calendar.SATURDAY:
        break;
}
```

Now with `calendar`, you can get any thing you want. Here is more information for [Calendar on Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK).

Comment: I'm trying your sample and I have one problem. I've inserted "2015-03-17" and the date result is Tue Mar, however, in the switch statement I get the 7 = Sat. Actually I should get the 3 = TUESDAY.

Comment: please see the edited code. I have used `calendar.get()` method now and it is working fine. Thanks for this edit :)